# Is there a different between using an npm package in Node.js vs using it in React / webpack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

To using the npm package [countries-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-data), for example, using Node.js, it is so simple:

```
$ npm install countries-data
$ node
var countries = require('country-data').countries;
countries.TW        // => {  ... the object }
countries.TW.name   // => "Taiwan"
```

However, if I do this in React:

```
import CountryData from "country-data";

console.log(CountryData.countries.TW);  // => undefined
```

I got `undefined`.  Searching in http://localhost:8080/bundle.js I do see the line

```
"name": "Taiwan"
```

Is it just that I didn't initialize it or something, which `require` did?

Comment: Did you try CountryData.TW?

Comment: just tried it... `CountryData.TW undefined`