# using npm package in react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have some ad-hoc javascript knowledge and am trying to learn react, but can't seem to locate documentation on how to use imports correctly.  Specifically, I have a quick app that fetches a value from an api I set up, and I would like to format the number using katex.  There is a react-katex package I installed using npm, but the instructions don't seem to cover how to accomplish this using webpack/jsx/whatever.

More specifically, how would I use the package?  The documentation says to use it thus

```
var BlockMath = ReactKaTeX.BlockMath;

ReactDOM.render(<BlockMath math="\\int_0^\\infty x^2 dx"/>, document.getElementById('katex-element'));
```

but when I do this in the example code below I get an error that the element `katex-element` is undefined.  I realize (I think) that the first line is replaced by the `import` command, so I know I don't need that, but where do I put the BlockMath call to get it to render the number in tex?

Here is my example app, I've tried a few things, but I either end up getting undefined errors, or no result at all:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
// ?? import 'react-katex';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      number: 0
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:4001/api/get_number')
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          number: data.number
        })
      })
  }
  render() {
    const number = this.state.number
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          Also <span id="katexElement">{number}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I think there is a similar question here: [Is there a different between using an npm package in Node.js vs using it in React / webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156960/is-there-a-different-between-using-an-npm-package-in-node-js-vs-using-it-in-reac)

Comment: have you tried, `import {InlineMath, BlockMath} from 'react-katex'` ?

Comment: Yes, and I think this gets the functions imported, but then how do you actually use them?  This is the part I can't seem to figure out.  The documentation seems to be for when you use react in a standard web document, not using jsx

Comment: you just use `<InlineMath math="\\int_0^\\infty x^2 dx"/>`. Add this in your jsx. but dont forget one thing as they said "Don't forget to import KaTeX CSS file (see example/index.html)."

Comment: So I just change my line `<span id="katexElement">{number}</span>` to `<InlineMath math="{number}"/>`?  I tried that before and got no result, maybe I am just doing something else wrong.

Comment: yes, that's the motive.

Comment: It seems that I'm probably not importing the stylesheet correctly then, could anyone point me to a resource that covers this?  I'm not seeing how to use the css included in a package, I figured it was just `import styles from 'react-katex'` but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can import it using

```
import {InlineMath, BlockMath} from 'react-katex'
```

Notice the `curly braces {}`, it will get only specified property from the library and not the whole library.

and can use these component directly in your jsx, like:

```
const inlineMath = (
    <div>
        <InlineMath math="\\int_0^\\infty x^2 dx"/>
    </div>
);
```

Notice: Please dont forget to add css.

> Don't forget to import KaTeX CSS file (see example/index.html).

Use this inside your `index.html` to import css in your code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/katex/dist/katex.min.css">
```

I would suggest you to use `{}` braces to get only the specific property from the library rather than loading the whole library at once. Also it makes the code much more clearer and readable.

Answer (score 1):

Using `import {InlineMath, BlockMath} from 'react-katex'` would let you leverage `InlineMath.function()`.

Alternatively, you should just be able to include

- `import ReactKatex from react-katex`

which would then allow you to access the entire library via `ReactKatex.subexport.function` where `subexport` is a nested module (such as `InlineMath` from the example above) and `function` is a defined function within that submodule.